# Data truncated for column 'x' when updating to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table containing a column named free_delivery_treshold of type float, NOT NULL **unchecked**.
If I insert data omitting this column, the default value (NULL) is inserted.
However, if I **update** its value to `NULL`, empty string or `\N` I get a

> WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED: Data truncated for column 'free_delivery_treshold' at row 1

error.

How do I update the value of this column to NULL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update `free_delivery_treshold` column to `NULL` you can try this.

you can't update `free_delivery_treshold` be empty string or `\N` because the type is `float`

```
CREATE TABLE T(free_delivery_treshold  float);

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);

UPDATE T
SET free_delivery_treshold =NULL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ecd8/1/0)**:

```
| free_delivery_treshold |
|------------------------|
|                 (null) |
```

---

if you want to update `NULL` data to empty string or `\N` you need to use `char` or `varchar` instead of float.

```
CREATE TABLE T(free_delivery_treshold  varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES (NULL);

UPDATE T
SET free_delivery_treshold =''
WHERE free_delivery_treshold IS NULL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ecd8/1/0)**:

```
| free_delivery_treshold |
|------------------------|
|                        |
```

Comment: @GaussianBlurs It worked in sqlfiddle. did you want to update `free_delivery_treshold` to `NULL`?

Comment: Thank you, I was writing SET `free_delivery_treshold="NULL"` instead of `free_delivery_treshold=NULL`

Comment: Haha yes `NULL != "NULL"`,`NULL` mean I don't know `"NULL"` is a string value.